# SQL order by rand() fill result with duplicates if there's not enough rows

Tags: mysql, sql, random, duplicates, sql-order-by

I have an exercising app for a language for running tests in 20,40,60 (LIMIT 20..40..60).
How to fill result by duplicates if LIMIT exceeds rows in selected topic?

table: topic Cooking has only 18 rows

Lets say "select from table where topic=Cooking order by rand() LIMIT 40

How to populate result by duplicates so that result has 40 rows even there is not enough rows for it?

```
table
--------------------------------------
rice
chair
spoon
knife
fork

wanted output - select * order by rand() limit 10
------------------------------------------
chair, rice, spoon, chair, knife, spoon, fork, knife, rice, fork 
-------------------
// forced 10 terms
```

Comment: Please show sample results along with what you want the extra rows to look like?

Answer (score 1):

This is probably better done in the application.  But if you must, you can multiply the number of rows and then order and `limit`:

```
select t.*
from t cross join
     (select 1 as n union all select 2 union all select 3 . . . 
      select 40
     ) n
where t.topic = 'Cooking'
order by n.n, rand()
limit 40;
```

You may not need 40 rows in the temporary table if you know that there is a certain minimum for your `where` clauses.

Comment: This answer seems to me like a reasonable interpretation of the question that was asked.

Answer (score 0):

```
    SELECT * FROM
((SELECT *, 1 sortby FROM dictionary where topic='Describing weather' order by rand())
UNION ALL 
(SELECT *, 2 sortby FROM dictionary where topic='Describing weather' order by rand())
)dum 
ORDER BY sortby
```

Comment: Please don't post only code as answer, but also provide an explanation what your code does and how it solves the problem of the question. Answers with an explanation are usually more helpful and of better quality, and are more likely to attract upvotes.